# Leer 2 veces o más la misma linea de un txt y remplazar segun los datos que te pidan

Tags: java

Tengo esta función en mi programa (entradaDatos); lo que hace es lee un archivo tipo txt; que es una platilla de un documento; "busca", cambia los datos e imprime en otro documento la plantilla con los cambios, el problema es que cuando 2 o más datos están en la misma linea no los cambia, alguna idea de como leer 2 veces y cambiarlo o hay otra forma que se les ocurra

También hay veces que cuando son 2 cambios de palabra si lo hace :v

Dejo link de un ejemplo del txt:  http://dl.free.fr/i4IQD6OwR

```
public void entradaDatos(File archivo,String Nombre,String Paterno,String Materno, 
            String Tel,String Email ,String Hospital, String Enfermedad, 
            String Domicilio, String LoqNecesita, String TipoAmparo,String numero){
        
        
        SimpleDateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMMM-yyyy");
        Date fecha = new Date();
        
        
        int r=(int)(Math.random()*1000+1);
        String nombreArchivo=Nombre+" "+Paterno+" "+Materno+" "+TipoAmparo+" "+r;
        String temp=simple.format(fecha);
        String aux;
        
        
        try {
            if(archivo.exists()){
                File fichero = new File(nombreArchivo+".txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fichero);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os) );
                /*Lee el documento hasta el final
va leyendo linea por linea
si encuentra en el documento la palabra clave que esta entre "@" entra en el if y hace
un remplazo de cada palabra clave que encuentra

                */
                    while((aux=br.readLine())!= null){
                        
                         if(aux.contains("@Nombre@") || aux.contains("@Email@") 
                                 ||aux.contains("@Telefono@")|| aux.contains("@Domicilio@") 
                                 ||aux.contains("@Hospital@") || aux.contains("@Enfermedad@") 
                                 || aux.contains("@Med@") || aux.contains("@NumeroDerecho@")
                                 || aux.contains("@dia/mes/año@")){
                            
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Nombre@", Nombre+" "+Paterno+" "+Materno);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Email@", Email);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Nombre@", Tel);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Domicilio@", Domicilio);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Hospital@", Hospital);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Enfermedad@", Enfermedad);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Med@", LoqNecesita);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@NumeroDerecho@", numero);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@dia/mes/año@", temp);
                            
                            
                            
                    } 
                        pw.println(aux);   
                    }
                pw.close();
                br.close(); 
            }
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Su archivo no se pudo crear");
        }
        

            
    }
```

Comment: podrías hacer un método recursivo, que revise después de los replace si quedan aún elementos por reemplazar, si quedan, que haga el replace de nuevo, si no, libera la línea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de probar tu programa con el archivo de muestra que dejaste, y funciona bien, me generó un archivo que lo puedes ver aquí: https://pastebin.com/km7tKpRJ

El único problema, es que te olvidaste de reemplazar el token @telefono@ (pusiste 2 veces @nombre@), y quizá por eso parezca que no lo procesa, pero lo hace.

Fíjate si eso soluciona tu problema y deja un comentario en esta respuesta en caso de que no.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice @Alex. Yo también lo he probado y me funciona perfecto, y también es cierto lo del token @telefono@ y lo del @nombre@. Tal vez el error no este en el código que nos pusiste. Revisa nuevamente y dinos si sigues teniendo en mismo problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si tenia que cambiar aux=aux.replaceAll("@Nombre@", Tel); por aux=aux.replaceAll("@Telefono@", Tel); y lo cambia; la verdad ni me había percatado de el error en el código;

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar un flag... algo así, que seguirá preguntando en la misma linea hasta que no existan condiciones y luego pasará a la siguiente linea

```
public void entradaDatos(File archivo,String Nombre,String Paterno,String Materno, 
            String Tel,String Email ,String Hospital, String Enfermedad, 
            String Domicilio, String LoqNecesita, String TipoAmparo,String numero){
        
        
        SimpleDateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMMM-yyyy");
        Date fecha = new Date();
        
        
        int r=(int)(Math.random()*1000+1);
        String nombreArchivo=Nombre+" "+Paterno+" "+Materno+" "+TipoAmparo+" "+r;
        String temp=simple.format(fecha);
        String aux;
        Bool bFlag=true;
        
        try {
            if(archivo.exists()){
                File fichero = new File(nombreArchivo+".txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fichero);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os) );
                /*Lee el documento hasta el final
va leyendo linea por linea
si encuentra en el documento la palabra clave que esta entre "@" entra en el if y hace
un remplazo de cada palabra clave que encuentra

                */
                    while((aux=br.readLine())!= null){
                        bFlag=true;
                        while(bflag){
                         if(aux.contains("@Nombre@") || aux.contains("@Email@") 
                                 ||aux.contains("@Telefono@")|| aux.contains("@Domicilio@") 
                                 ||aux.contains("@Hospital@") || aux.contains("@Enfermedad@") 
                                 || aux.contains("@Med@") || aux.contains("@NumeroDerecho@")
                                 || aux.contains("@dia/mes/año@")){
                            
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Nombre@", Nombre+" "+Paterno+" "+Materno);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Email@", Email);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Nombre@", Tel);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Domicilio@", Domicilio);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Hospital@", Hospital);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Enfermedad@", Enfermedad);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@Med@", LoqNecesita);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@NumeroDerecho@", numero);
                            aux=aux.replaceAll("@dia/mes/año@", temp);
                            
                        }
                        else{
                            bFlag=false 
                        }   
                    } 
                    
                    } 
                        pw.println(aux);   
                    }
                pw.close();
                br.close(); 
            }
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Su archivo no se pudo crear");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia!!!! :D